# Granting directory level permissions for Google Cloud Storage REST APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, acl

My aim is to be able to call the Google Storage REST APIs with an OAuth token granting an authenticated Google user the read/write permissions on a directory called "directoryName" inside my storage bucket.

So, far I have successfully managed to use the Storage APIs after adding the user to the ACL for the bucket. However, I do not want to grant the user the READ or WRITE permissions on the complete bucket but just on the user's directory inside the bucket e.g. bucket/directoryName.

e.g. I want to be able to call storage.objects.list for a directory inside the bucket without providing the user the permissions for the bucket but just for that directory (and subdirectories).

What I've tried so far: When I tried to call the GET method on  https://www.googleapis.com//storage/v1/b/bucket/o?fields=kind%2Citems%28name%29&maxResults=150&prefix=directoryName with the user added to the directory's ACL (as Owner), I get the error response "code":403,"message":"myEmail@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to myBucketName.appspot.com."

Is it possible to provide directory level permissions with Google Cloud Storage and list the contents of that directory only?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations), there are no such thing as directories in Cloud Storage. As far as Storage is concerned, there are only buckets and inside them objects/files that may or may not have "/" in their name.

Due to this design choice, there's no option to set permissions on a "directory" in Cloud Storage. Please note however that you can create as many buckets as you want for no extra charge. You may create one bucket per user to fit your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that there are no such thing as directories and I was refer to objects in the bucket ending with "/" as directories.  I can add bucket levelpermisions to users however according to https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas , I can only create 1 bucket every 2 seconds. . This is severely limiting as I expect to be adding more than 1 user per 2 seconds  to my application .  Do you know any workarounds?